# How to get instance of Currently Shown UItextField in Page Control

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uipagecontrol

How Can i get instance of Currently Shown `UItextField` in `PageControl` as i am allocating the `UItextField` i am getting the instance of `UItextField` on the last page in `PageControl`

Comment: please be descriptive while asking questions follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a typecast. This code will do it:
first you need to set tag property of UITextField like

```
yourTextField.tag = 123
```

now you can get yourTextField by using tag property like

```
if let theTextField = self.view.viewWithTag(123) as? UITextField {
    theLabel.text = "some text"
}
```